# How to bring to html file JSON Data created in Jquery using Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working with some JSON data, which is selected by a daterangepicker and need to combine it with Morris JS.

In Ajax's URL, I am sending my function to a file, from which will be getting an array. I want to receive that array in a separate php file.

This is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "ajax/datatable-adminventas.ajax.php",
   method: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {fechaInicial: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'), 
   fechaFinal: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')},
   success: function(respuesta){
    console.log(respuesta);
   }
});
```

Then, I want to make this validation in my PHP. (It is returning the NULL variables):

```
  if (isset($_GET['fechaInicial'])) {
    echo 'get has a value';
    $fechaInicial = $_GET["fechaInicial"];
    $fechaFinal = $_GET["fechaFinal"];
  } else {
    $fechaInicial = null;
    $fechaFinal = null;
    echo 'null variables';
    }
```

Comment: Try quoting your keys `{'fechaInicial': moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')}`

Comment: Didnt work :( I want to receive those GET variables but I havent achieved so!

Comment: Maybe try using double quotes in your php? `if (isset($_GET["fechaInicial"])) {` In my experience, php is finicky about quotes and double quotes.

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: Hmm, that usually fixes it for me haha. A quick read of the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/),  ` dataType:
The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.`  Since you're echoing a string, that could cause problems.